# Download image from url and show it into real device gallery android?

Tags: android, memory, internal

Using this code to download image from url in internal stroage. It working properly and showing image in emulator but When debugging on real device it gives empty.. Help me...

```
File fileWithinMyDir = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
downloadImage(url1, fileWithinMyDir.getAbsolutePath()+MODE_WORLD_READABLE + "/" +"image1.jpg");

public boolean downloadImage(String URL,String fileName){

        try 
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            URL url = new URL(URL);
            File file = new File(fileName);
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) 
            {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: First of all I will strongly recommend to use `Asynctask` instead of doing this in main thread using `StrictMode`

Comment: for that I am using StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);..

Comment: I will use the asynctask but right now this is not my problem..

Comment: is there any solution ?

Comment: Have you added the required permission for that in manifest file.

Comment: Like, write or read external storage, as well as access network state etc...

Comment: but i am storing it into external storage

Comment: It showing on emulator DDMS but not showing in device internal memory..

Comment: For storing file you need to pass permission in android manifest file,  like, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` , `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`,

Comment: thanks but not working ..

Comment: You cannot view the contents of `getFilesDir()` on a production Android device using DDMS, unless you have rooted that device. So, if that is how you are trying to test whether your file is downloaded, your test is flawed. Do something *in your app* to indicate that the file was downloaded.

Comment: you will nt get solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

If your device is connected with USB cable run your App & remove device from USB cable and check it. I hop it will work.
And it will not work use the fallowing code

```
        String serverURL1 = "enter your image url";
                        new imageFile().execute(serverURL1);


public class imageFile extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
{
    private Context context;    
    public void setContext(Context contextf)
    {
        context = contextf;
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) 
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(arg0[0]);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.connect();    
            File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"SD card path");
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;

            while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0 )
            {
                f.write(buffer,0, len1);    
            }
            f.close();

            }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("imageFile", "Update error! " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }}  
//Animation class focus on windows button change 
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) 
    {
        frameAnimation.start();
    }
    else 
    {
        frameAnimation.stop();
    }
}
```